# JQuery disables my button before the codebehind executes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, imagebutton

I have an Asp.net (Ver4) web page with an imageButton that is used to submit the form data to a database via the code behind of the imagebuttons click event. In the code behind I am using a response.redirect to move them to a thank you page, it is the last line in the code behind routine. 
Due to the DB being a little slow sometimes I want to disable the click event until the page is redirected. I am attempting to do this with jquery. I have been able to disable the button and make it appear disabled but then my code behind is not firing at all.

This is the JQuery I am using

```
function test() {
    $("#ImageButton1").attr("disabled", "disabled").css('opacity',' 0.5');
}
```

This is the aspx code for the button

```
<div class="button">
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="28px"
           OnClientClick="test();"
           onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
           ImageUrl="media/finishbutton.jpg" 
           style="margin-top: 0px" Width="97px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look into the rendered HTML code to see if the image button really has the ID `ImageButton1` because .net generates it a little different if your code is in a user control for example (thats why  some people wrote `<%=ImageButton1.ClientID %>` in the answers). Try to execute your test method from the console without clicking the button to see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to disable the element a little bit later after the click event has triggered. For example:

```
 function test() {
    setTimeout(function () { $("#<%=ImageButton1.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", "disabled").css('opacity', ' 0.5'); }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 function test() {
$("#<%=ImageButton1.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", "disabled").css('opacity',' 0.5');
//$("#ImageButton1").css('opacity', ' 0.5');

}
```

and in aspx

```
 <div class="button">
          <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="28px" OnClientClick="javascript:test();"
              onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
              ImageUrl="media/finishbutton.jpg" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="97px" />
        </div>
```

Comment: I did try all other methods including checking the clientID. since this is not in a user control or in a complex page the id name was not changed in the rendered HTML. However this is good to know that my id's may be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `return true;` at the end of your `test()` function

Answer (score 0):

You could add beforeAsyncPostBack and disable the button there like described [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=256), or just return true from the click handler. Also, you might want to use the clientID to disable the button instead of just the element ID, which is what the server understands.